# How to properly use else and break to print out result when the condition is not reached?

Tags: python

```
cube = 8
for guess in range(cube+1):
    if guess**3 == cube :
        print("Cube root of ", cube ," is ", guess)
    else :
        print("No integer cube is found ")
```

The result print out "No integer cube is found" several times, why ? Another one I tried is :

```
cube = 8
for guess in range(cube+1):
    if guess**3 == cube :
        print("Cube root of ", cube ," is ", guess)
    else:
        if guess**3 != cube :
            break
print("No integer cube is found ")
```

It just print the last line. Very confused in both ways. Thank you in advance

Comment: This would be a *great* time to learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: Follow the execution logic step by step here: http://pythontutor.com…

Comment: You shouldn't print the "not found" message inside the loop, because it might be found later. You have to print it *after* the loop is done if it never found what it's looking for.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a flag variable to keep track of whether an integer cube root has been found.
Example

```py
cube = 8
found = False

for guess in range(cube+1):
    if guess**3 == cube:
        print("Cube root of", cube, "is", guess)
        found = True
        break

if not found:
    print("No integer cube root found")
```